# Rolling window regressions within multiple groups

Tags: r, rollapply

I am trying to apply a rolling window regression model to multiple groups in my data. Part of my data is as below:

```
     gvkey year          LC      YTO
1   001004 1972   0.1919713 2.021182
2   001004 1973   0.2275895 2.029056
3   001004 1974   0.3341368 2.053517
4   001004 1975   0.3313518 2.090532
5   001004 1976   0.4005829 2.136939
6   001004 1977   0.4471945 2.123909
7   001004 1978   0.4442004 2.150281
8   001004 1979   0.5054544 2.173162
9   001004 1980   0.5269449 2.188077
10  001004 1981   0.5423774 2.200805
11  001004 1982   0.3528982 2.200851
12  001004 1983   0.3674031 2.190487
13  001004 1984   0.2267620 2.181291
14  001004 1985   0.2796132 2.159443
15  001004 1986   0.3382120 2.128420
16  001004 1987   0.3214131 2.089670
17  001004 1988   0.3883732 2.048279
18  001004 1989   0.4466488 1.999539
19  001004 1990   0.4929991 1.955500
20  001004 1991   0.5150894 1.934893
21  001004 1992   0.5218845 1.925521
22  001004 1993   0.5038105 1.904241
23  001004 1994   0.5041639 1.881731
24  001004 1995   0.5196658 1.863143
25  001004 1996   0.5352994 1.844464
26  001004 1997   0.4556059 1.835676
27  001004 1998   0.4905767 1.837886
28  001004 1999   0.5471959 1.824636
29  001004 2000   0.5920976 1.814944
30  001004 2001   0.5998172 1.893943
31  001004 2002   0.4499911 1.889703
32  001004 2003   0.4207154 1.870703
33  001004 2004   0.4371594 1.831638
34  001004 2005   0.4525900 1.802684
35  001004 2006   0.4342149 1.781757
36  001004 2007   0.4899473 1.753360
37  001004 2008   0.5436673 1.680464
38  001004 2009   0.5873861 1.612499
39  001004 2010   0.5216734 1.544322
40  001004 2011   0.5592963 1.415892
41  001004 2012   0.5627509 1.407393
42  001004 2013   0.5904637 1.384202
43  001004 2014   0.6170085 1.353340
44  001004 2015   0.7145900 1.314014
45  001007 1975   0.3721916 2.090532
46  001007 1976   0.2760902 2.136939
47  001007 1977   0.1866554 2.123909
48  001007 1978   0.1977654 2.150281
49  001007 1979   0.1927100 2.173162
50  001007 1980   0.2112344 2.188077
51  001007 1981  -0.2141724 2.200805
52  001007 1982  -0.2072785 2.200851
53  001007 1983  -1.7406963 2.190487
54  001007 1984 -14.8071429 2.181291
55  001009 1982  -1.2753247 2.200851
56  001009 1983   1.3349904 2.190487
57  001009 1984   2.6192237 2.181291
58  001009 1985   0.5867925 2.159443
59  001009 1986   0.6959436 2.128420
60  001009 1987   0.7142857 2.089670
61  001009 1988   0.7771897 2.048279
62  001009 1989   0.8293820 1.999539
63  001009 1990   0.8655382 1.955500
64  001009 1991   0.8712144 1.934893
65  001009 1992   0.8882548 1.925521
66  001009 1993   0.9190540 1.904241
67  001009 1994   0.9411806 1.881731
68  001010 1971   0.6492499 2.002337
69  001010 1972   0.6667664 2.021182
70  001010 1973   0.6840115 2.029056
71  001010 1974   0.7011797 2.053517
72  001010 1975   0.7189469 2.090532
73  001010 1976   0.7367344 2.136939
74  001010 1977   0.7511779 2.123909
75  001010 1978   0.7673365 2.150281
76  001010 1979   0.7795880 2.173162
77  001010 1980   0.7824448 2.188077
78  001010 1981   0.7821913 2.200805
79  001010 1982   0.7646078 2.200851
80  001010 1983   0.7426172 2.190487
81  001010 1984  -0.0657935 2.181291
82  001010 1985   0.2802410 2.159443
83  001010 1986   0.2052373 2.128420
84  001010 1987   0.2465290 2.089670
85  001010 1988   0.3437856 2.048279
86  001010 1989   0.7398662 1.999539
87  001010 1990   0.6360582 1.955500
88  001010 1991   0.7790707 1.934893
89  001010 1992   0.7588472 1.925521
90  001010 1993   0.7695341 1.904241
91  001010 1994   0.8060759 1.881731
92  001010 1995   0.8381234 1.863143
93  001010 1996   0.8661541 1.844464
94  001010 1997   0.8700456 1.835676
95  001010 1998   0.8748443 1.837886
96  001010 1999   0.8884077 1.824636
97  001010 2000   0.8979903 1.814944
98  001010 2003   0.6812689 1.870703
99  001011 1983   0.3043007 2.190487
100 001011 1984   0.3080601 2.181291
```

My function is

```
Match.LC.YTO<-function(x){rollapplyr(x,width=10,by.column=F,fill=NA, FUN=function(m){
  temp.1<-lm(LC~YTO,data=m)
  summary(temp.1)$r.squared*(sign(summary(temp.1)$coefficients[2,1]))
})}

df<-df%>%group_by(gvkey)%>%mutate(MTCH=Match.LC.YTO(df))
```

My data is grouped by gvkey, and for each group I need to calculate a variable named "MTCH" which equals the R squared value times the sign of coefficient of YTO in the linear model `LC~YTO`, and the model is estimated at a rolling window of 10 observations. I got the error message:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  'data' must be a data.frame, not a matrix or an array
```

I have checked many other posts concerning the function rollapply and rollapplyr, and some suggest that I need to convert my df to zoo or matrix before I use rollapply function, but it still did not work.

Comment: @BWilliams I did try transforming my data frame to zoo format, but it still did not work. In addition, my error message is different from that one.

Comment: @BWilliams, Although the questions may be appear similar the problems here are actually different.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rollapply` in zoo will accept plain matrix and data frame arguments.  That is not the problem. The following are problems with this code:

- the code passes a matrix to `lm` but `lm` takes a data.frame
- the code attempts to use `rollapply` with width of 10 on an object with fewer than 10 rows in the last group
- if the intercept fits perfectly then there will be no 2nd coefficient from `lm` so the reference to `coefficients[2, 1]` will fail with an error.

Although not erroneous the following are areas for improvement:

- `TRUE` and `FALSE` should be written out in full since `T` and `F` are valid variable names making this highly error-prone.
- when using `group_by` in dplyr always match it with an `ungroup`.  If you don't do that then the output will remember the grouping and the next time you use the output you will get a surprise.  For example, consider the differnce between the following two snippets. The first results in `n` being the number of elements in the group that that row belongs to whereas the second results in the `n` being the number of rows in `out`.

  ```
  out <- df %>% group_by(gvkey) %>% mutate(MTCH = Match.LC.YTO(LC, YTO))
  out %>% mutate(n = n())

  out <- df %>% group_by(gvkey) %>% mutate(MTCH = Match.LC.YTO(LC, YTO)) %>% ungroup
  out %>% mutate(n = n())
  ```
- questions to SO should be self-contained and reproducible so the `library` statements should not be omitted and the data should be provided in a reproducible manner

To fix these problems we

- use `partial = TRUE` in `rollapply` to allow it to pass objects with fewer than 10 rows.
- pass the variables involved directly
- `rollapply` over the row numbers.
- add an `NA` to the end of the coefficients to be picked up if the coefficient vector otherwise has only 1 element.
- for clarity we have separated out the `lm_summary` function which was anonymous in the question
- for reproduciblity we have added `library` statements and the Note at the end

The revised code is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

Match.LC.YTO <- function(LC, YTO) {

   lm_summary <- function(ix) {
      temp.1 <- lm(LC ~ YTO, subset = ix)
      summary(temp.1)$r.squared * sign(c(coef(temp.1), NA)[2])
   }

   rollapplyr(seq_along(LC), width = 10, FUN = lm_summary, partial = TRUE)
}

df %>% group_by(gvkey) %>% mutate(MTCH = Match.LC.YTO(LC, YTO)) %>% ungroup
```

If you would rather use `fill = NA` insted of `partial = TRUE` then add a check for the series length being less than the series width, i.e. less than 10:

```
Match.LC.YTO2 <- function(LC, YTO) {

   lm_summary <- function(ix) {
      temp.1 <- lm(LC ~ YTO, subset = ix)
      summary(temp.1)$r.squared * sign(c(coef(temp.1), NA)[2])
   }

  if (length(LC) < 10) return(NA) ##
  rollapplyr(seq_along(LC), width = 10, FUN = lm_summary, fill = NA)
}

df %>% group_by(gvkey) %>% mutate(MTCH = Match.LC.YTO2(LC, YTO)) %>% ungroup
```

### Note 1

For sake of reproducibility we used this as the input `df`:

```
Lines <- "     gvkey year          LC      YTO
1   001004 1972   0.1919713 2.021182
2   001004 1973   0.2275895 2.029056
3   001004 1974   0.3341368 2.053517
4   001004 1975   0.3313518 2.090532
5   001004 1976   0.4005829 2.136939
6   001004 1977   0.4471945 2.123909
7   001004 1978   0.4442004 2.150281
8   001004 1979   0.5054544 2.173162
9   001004 1980   0.5269449 2.188077
10  001004 1981   0.5423774 2.200805
11  001004 1982   0.3528982 2.200851
12  001004 1983   0.3674031 2.190487
13  001004 1984   0.2267620 2.181291
14  001004 1985   0.2796132 2.159443
15  001004 1986   0.3382120 2.128420
16  001004 1987   0.3214131 2.089670
17  001004 1988   0.3883732 2.048279
18  001004 1989   0.4466488 1.999539
19  001004 1990   0.4929991 1.955500
20  001004 1991   0.5150894 1.934893
21  001004 1992   0.5218845 1.925521
22  001004 1993   0.5038105 1.904241
23  001004 1994   0.5041639 1.881731
24  001004 1995   0.5196658 1.863143
25  001004 1996   0.5352994 1.844464
26  001004 1997   0.4556059 1.835676
27  001004 1998   0.4905767 1.837886
28  001004 1999   0.5471959 1.824636
29  001004 2000   0.5920976 1.814944
30  001004 2001   0.5998172 1.893943
31  001004 2002   0.4499911 1.889703
32  001004 2003   0.4207154 1.870703
33  001004 2004   0.4371594 1.831638
34  001004 2005   0.4525900 1.802684
35  001004 2006   0.4342149 1.781757
36  001004 2007   0.4899473 1.753360
37  001004 2008   0.5436673 1.680464
38  001004 2009   0.5873861 1.612499
39  001004 2010   0.5216734 1.544322
40  001004 2011   0.5592963 1.415892
41  001004 2012   0.5627509 1.407393
42  001004 2013   0.5904637 1.384202
43  001004 2014   0.6170085 1.353340
44  001004 2015   0.7145900 1.314014
45  001007 1975   0.3721916 2.090532
46  001007 1976   0.2760902 2.136939
47  001007 1977   0.1866554 2.123909
48  001007 1978   0.1977654 2.150281
49  001007 1979   0.1927100 2.173162
50  001007 1980   0.2112344 2.188077
51  001007 1981  -0.2141724 2.200805
52  001007 1982  -0.2072785 2.200851
53  001007 1983  -1.7406963 2.190487
54  001007 1984 -14.8071429 2.181291
55  001009 1982  -1.2753247 2.200851
56  001009 1983   1.3349904 2.190487
57  001009 1984   2.6192237 2.181291
58  001009 1985   0.5867925 2.159443
59  001009 1986   0.6959436 2.128420
60  001009 1987   0.7142857 2.089670
61  001009 1988   0.7771897 2.048279
62  001009 1989   0.8293820 1.999539
63  001009 1990   0.8655382 1.955500
64  001009 1991   0.8712144 1.934893
65  001009 1992   0.8882548 1.925521
66  001009 1993   0.9190540 1.904241
67  001009 1994   0.9411806 1.881731
68  001010 1971   0.6492499 2.002337
69  001010 1972   0.6667664 2.021182
70  001010 1973   0.6840115 2.029056
71  001010 1974   0.7011797 2.053517
72  001010 1975   0.7189469 2.090532
73  001010 1976   0.7367344 2.136939
74  001010 1977   0.7511779 2.123909
75  001010 1978   0.7673365 2.150281
76  001010 1979   0.7795880 2.173162
77  001010 1980   0.7824448 2.188077
78  001010 1981   0.7821913 2.200805
79  001010 1982   0.7646078 2.200851
80  001010 1983   0.7426172 2.190487
81  001010 1984  -0.0657935 2.181291
82  001010 1985   0.2802410 2.159443
83  001010 1986   0.2052373 2.128420
84  001010 1987   0.2465290 2.089670
85  001010 1988   0.3437856 2.048279
86  001010 1989   0.7398662 1.999539
87  001010 1990   0.6360582 1.955500
88  001010 1991   0.7790707 1.934893
89  001010 1992   0.7588472 1.925521
90  001010 1993   0.7695341 1.904241
91  001010 1994   0.8060759 1.881731
92  001010 1995   0.8381234 1.863143
93  001010 1996   0.8661541 1.844464
94  001010 1997   0.8700456 1.835676
95  001010 1998   0.8748443 1.837886
96  001010 1999   0.8884077 1.824636
97  001010 2000   0.8979903 1.814944
98  001010 2003   0.6812689 1.870703
99  001011 1983   0.3043007 2.190487
100 001011 1984   0.3080601 2.181291"

df <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

### Note 2

The check for length in the line marked with ## at the end is no longer necessary as recent versions of zoo automatically make this check.

Comment: Thanks so much, your code runs perfectly with my example data. However, when I tried to apply it to my data, I got error message "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'y' ". I have checked all my Y observations and there is no NA/NaN/Inf, so I am not sure what could be the issue.